# Creating a shell script to set up a folder action

Tags: macos, shell, action, directory

Is it possible to create a shell script that can enable and set up a folder action script in Mac OS X? I need the script so that I can add it to a package to deploy to multiple computers. I have tried searching online and cannot seem to find anything about whether this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

`osascript` is the command to use-:

```
osascript applescript-file
```